# Smoothing banding noise of scanned photos

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to filter this kind of banding noise on dark areas of scanned images. I have already removed pattern noise with FFT filtering and applied some median filter. All the bright parts of the images look great, but darker patches look like this:

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to smooth these patches without losing detail in the brighter ones ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Neat Image software works very well at removing this type of noise:

[image]

Really worth the 35euros for this software.